# How to remove Russian and Arabic strings from a text file

Tags: text-processing, character-encoding, unicode

**Problem:**
I have text file with approximately 1M lines, each line consists of multiple words
Some lines contain Russian or Arabic words (lets call them "bad lines"), I want to remove only these bad lines. The others are "good lines".

**Conditions:**

- There are non-ascii characters in some of good lines, so just removing everything non-ascii doesn't solve the problem.
- Each line is either completely bad or good, so this actually makes things a little bit easier.

So the solution that came to my mind is to just:

```
sort file.txt > sorted.txt
```

Anything starting with Russian or Arabic will be listed at the end. And then I will manually check the line they begin and then do

```
head -n X sorted.txt > clean.txt
```

to get rid of them. 
Is there a more elegant way to do this? What other Unix tools can be used to accomplish this task.

Sample input:

```
kedi
cat
кошка
القط
candy
şeker
конфеты
كاندي
çağrı
resumé
```

Desired output:

```
kedi
cat
candy
şeker
çağrı
resumé
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work at least for your example:

```
$ perl -CS -Mutf8 -lne 's{ 
            (?= [\p{Arabic}\p{Cyrillic}] ) 
            [\p{Arabic}\p{Cyrillic}\p{Common}\p{Inherited}] + 
            (?<= [\p{Arabic}\p{Cyrillic}] ) }{}xg || print' < file

kedi
cat
candy
şeker
çağrı
resumé
```

The basic idea is to use the `\p` to define a set of code points, in this case Arabic or Cyrillic and if a line matches, it will not be printed. Unfortunately, I don't understand the details myself, this was provided by [@tchrist](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2649/tchrist) in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18255967#18255967). I suggest you read his description there. I don't have time to decipher the regex now but I will add an explanation as soon as I get a chance to understand it myself. Given the source, I am assuming it is more complete and safer than my minimalist version below.

---

A simplified version of this that falls within my own understanding is

```
$ perl  -CS -ne '/[\p{Arabic}\p{Cyrillic}]+/ || print' < file
```

That will print all lines that don't contain any Arabic or Cyrillic characters *only*. The  `-CS` tells `perl` that STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR are all unicode. The `-ne` means "read each input line and apply the script given by `-e`. The `/foo/ || bar` means do `bar` if the line does not match `foo`. In this case, print if the line does not match any Arabic or Cyrillic characters.

Finally, the `\p{}` is (from `man perluniprops`):

```
   The Perl regular expression "\p{}" and "\P{}" constructs give access to
   most of the Unicode character properties.
```

This allows you to match a range of characters such as Arabic or Cyrillic or pretty much anything else you can think of. Therefore, the *characters class* `[\p{foo}]` will match any character of the script `foo`. So, `[\p{Arabic}\p{Cyrillic}]` will match any characters of the two scripts.

Comment: I should have probably emphasized **elegant** in my question, just kidding :) As Cyrillic as it seems, this actually works and enables me to automate the cleaning process. I will accept this answer but some explanation and any additional solution is most welcome. Now I think, http://i.imgur.com/zAe4U53.png

Comment: @GaniSimsek I know, I know :). The user I asked is both a serious Perl guru (he _writes_ the O'reilly books) and has a particular interest in language and computational linguistics. While I know enough Perl do be able to decipher this, I don't know enough to do it just by glancing. In the meantime, I have provided a shorter version that also works with your example and that I am actually capable of explaining. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, it indeed helps. And what if I wanted to extend unwanted languages to also include Chinese/Japanase/Korean? Trying your version as `$ perl -CS -ne '/[\p{Arabic}\p{Cyrillic}\p{CJK}]+/ || print' < file` or `p{Block: CJK}` gives this error: `Can't find Unicode property definition "CJK" at -e line 1, <> line 1.` I searched for this error but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: @GaniSimsek I really don't know. I only just found out about all this when I tried to answer your question. `perl -CS -ne '/[\p{Arabic}\p{Cyrillic}\p{CJK}]+/ || print' < file` works for me but I don't have any Japanese, Chinese or Korean to test with. Presumably, your perl doesn't have those. Not sure what you would need to install to get them. I suggest you ask on [SO] since this is becoming a pure programming issue.